# Elasticsearch data as input for all index and output as file for respective (index-name.txt)

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash

I am trying to send my Elasticsearch data to S3 using Logstash.
In the process, I have multiple ES indices which reside in the input filter of the Logstash.
I want to have different files for different indices with their name as file names.

Input Filter:-

```
input {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "index1,index2,index3,index4,index5,index6"              #Multiple indices as input
    query => '
    {
    "query": {
    "match_all": {}
    }
    }
  '
  }
}
```

Now I want to save the output of all the indices in a file with index as the filename.
Like : index1    --->    index1.txt

Output filter:-

```
output {
 s3 {
     region => *********
     bucket => ***********
     size_file => ********
     codec => "json"
     encoding => "gzip"
     prefix => "data/(indexName)/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}"
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `docinfo => true` setting in the Elasticsearch input to add `@metadata` fields about the source document. The setting is documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-docinfo). The field `[@metadata][_index]` will then be available for use in the output plugin.

An example based on your configuration:

```rb
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "index1,index2,index3,index4,index5,index6"
  }
}

output {
 s3 {
     region => *********
     bucket => ***********
     size_file => ********
     codec => "json"
     encoding => "gzip"
     prefix => "data/%{[@metadata][_index]}/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}"
   }

}
```

The two important changes I've made in this config, compared to yours, are:

1. Enabled `docinfo` in the input plugin
2. Replaced `(index)` with `%{[@metadata][_index]}` in the output plugin

For readability I also pruned the `match_all` query.